# Compare multidimensional array and return index

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.8.7

**Ruby 1.8.7**

```
array = [[1.5,"cm"],[1.5,"cm"],[1.5,"m"]]
```

How to compare each array inside the variable array and see if it is equal, 
if equal then move on else if not equal then return the index of the array element which was not equal and *stop comparing*.

So in this example,

```
array[0] == array[1] 
#=> true
```

Thus, move on

```
array[1] == array[2]
=> false
```

Hence return index i.e = 1

```
return 1
```

Comment: If all equal  then what to return ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit: The idea is to start comparing from the beginning and stop and return index when not the same, if all the values are the same then return nil

Comment: @MarkV what practical application do you have for such a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would do using [`Array#each_index`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/Array.html#method-i-each_index) :

```
def compare_array_elements(array)
  siz = array.size - 1
  array.each_index { |i| return i if i != siz && array[i] != array[i+1] }
  nil
end

array = [[1.5,"cm"],[1.5,"cm"],[1.5,"mm"]] 
compare_array_elements(array) # => 1

array = [[1.5,"cm"],[1.5,"cm"],[1.5,"cm"]]
compare_array_elements(array) # => nil
```

Comment: Instead of using the check against `siz` you could just do `array.each_index[0..-2]`

Comment: @TomFenech Same I am also thinking here in my desk. Again I am thinking if it would be Rubyish idea or not.. :-)

Comment: @TomFenech that should be `array[0..-2].each_index` BTW.. :)

Comment: Duly noted! Either way, shouldn't the check against `siz` be before the comparison so that it short-circuits the && rather than comparing against a `nil`?

Comment: @TomFenech Humm.. That's a Good idea.. Indeed

Answer (score 0):

```
[[1.5,"cm"],[1.5,"cm"],[1.5,"m"]]
.each_cons(2).with_index(1).find{|(a, b), i| a == b}.last
# => 1
```

Comment: ...but what does it mean?!